# Reactjs do not re-render when children node changed

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I contrusted a table-form with two children node buttons and rows using Reactjs.

After change the value of each child node, the parent node receive the new state,

but no re-render happened, why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> w3du </title><meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .quarcol {
            width:25%
        }
        .vmidcol {
            vertical-align:middle
        }
        .cyan {
            color:#fff;
            background-color:#63aae7
        }
        .blue {
            color:#fff;
            background-color:#60a0e0
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Panel</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/js-signals/1.0.0/js-signals.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel">
```

The 'table-row' stuff, the 3rd column is number, after modified, the associated button doesn't changed its value, vice versa

```js
    var BudgetTableRow = React.createClass({
        getInitialState : function(){
            return {
                n     : this.props.n,
                price : this.props.price
            };
        },
        handleChangeNum : function(e){
            this.setState({
                n : e.target.value
            });
            this.props.callback(this.props.idx, e.target.value);
        },
        render : function(){
            var styfull = {
                width : '100%',
                height : '30%',
            };
            var stycenter = {
                verticalAlign : 'middle',
                horizontalAlign : 'middle'
            };
            return (
                <tr className={this.props.color}>
                    <td className="quarcol text-center monofont" style={stycenter}>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title={"<h1>"+this.props.label+"</h1>"}>{this.props.name}</a>
                    </td>

                    <td className="quarcol"><input name={this.props.label+'-price'}
                        className="form-control text-center monofont"
                        type="text" defaultValue={this.state.price} style={styfull}
                        onChange={this.handleChangePrice}
                    /></td>

                    <td className="quarcol"><input name={this.props.label+'-n'} 
                        className="form-control text-center monofont"
                        type="text" defaultValue={this.state.n} style={styfull}
                        onChange={this.handleChangeNum} onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                    /></td>

                    <td className="quarcol text-center monofont" style={stycenter}>
                        {this.state.price * this.state.n}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        }
    });
```

The 'button' stuff, after modified, the associated table-row doesn't changed its value

```js
    var BudgetTableButton = React.createClass({
        getInitialState : function(){
            return {
                n : this.props.n
            };
        },
        handelClick : function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var n = (this.state.n=="0" || this.state.n=="") ? "1" : "0";
            this.setState({
                n : n
            });
            this.props.callback(this.props.idx, n);
        },
        render : function(){
            var cls = (this.state.n=="0" || this.state.n=="") ? null : 'btn-info';
            return (
                <button className={'btn ' + cls} onClick={this.handelClick}>{this.props.label} {this.state.n}</button>
            );
        }
    });
```

The parent node, the console.log() does right, but the form doesn't re-render, i used unique-key, is it something wrong with this.state.items.map ?

```js
    var BudgetTable = React.createClass({
        getInitialState : function(){
            return {
                items : this.props.items
            };
        },
        handleCallback : function(idx, n){
            var items = this.state.items;
            items[idx].n = n;
            this.setState({
                items : items
            });
        },
        render : function(){
            console.log(this.state.items[0]);
            return (
                <table className="table monofont">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="blue">
                            <td className="text-center" colSpan="4">Table</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td colSpan="4">
                            {this.state.items.map((it, idx) =>
                                <BudgetTableButton key={it.label+'r'} label={it.label} idx={idx} callback={this.handleCallback} n={it.n} />
                            )}
                        </td></tr>
                        {this.state.items.map((it, idx) =>
                            <BudgetTableRow key={it.label+'b'} label={it.label} name={it.name} price={it.price} idx={idx} callback={this.handleCallback} n={it.n} />
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            );
        }
    });
    function init(){
        return [
            { 
                "price": 1340, 
                "name": "shoe", 
                "label": "Q41",
                "n" : 1
            }, { 
                "price": 1290, 
                "name": "clothes", 
                "label": "Q42",
                "n" : 1
            }
        ];
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        <BudgetTable items={init()} />,
        document.getElementById("canvas")
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your example is that you are using two states.

(I will talk here about the button component, but both cases are the same)
As you probably already know, the local state can only trigger update on the component it belongs to.

You are trying to sync the button's state with the state of the main app. However **getInitialState** is only called on initial render and not on re-render ([info here](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/)).

In order to do what you want, you will need to get the button/row information from the **props** and not from the **state** (you already have them in props).

Furthermore, I would delete the children's state at all, because you don't need it. It is better that you keep the state in the top level component and only pass props and functions (like the callback fn) down to the children.

So in this case, if you change the button to the following code, it works flawlessly:

```
var BudgetTableButton = React.createClass({
    handelClick : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var n = this.props.n === "0" || this.props.n === "" ? "1" : "0";
        this.props.callback(this.props.idx, n);
    },
    render : function(){
        var cls = (this.props.n=="0" || this.props.n=="") ? null : 'btn-info';
        return (
            <button className={'btn ' + cls} onClick={this.handelClick}>{this.props.label} {this.props.n}</button>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: This problem bother me for a long time and now solved. I'm a non-native English speakers, I don't know how to express my gratitude properly, really really thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not mutating the state.

```
handleCallback : function(idx, n){
            var items = [...this.state.items];
            items[idx].n = n;
            this.setState({
                items : items
            });
        }
```

Comment: The state is correctly mutated. Otherwise the console.log would not display the correct data.